# Finding Alternative Accounts, SQL

Tags: sql

I have a setup like this:

```
Username | IP
Foo      | 1.2.3.4
Bar      | 1.2.3.4
Baz      | 1.2.3.6
```

Say I want to find alternative accounts of the user "Foo".  Something like this should return:

```
Username | IP
Bar      | 1.2.3.4
```

How would I do such a thing in one SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join should do the trick

this will give you all users that have more than one

```
Select * from 
Table t1
INNER JOIN Table t2
ON t1.ip = t2.ip
and t1.Username  <> t2.Username
```

you can adjust the where as you would want

e.g.

```
Where
 t1.UserName = 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
 LEFT JOIN TableName AS TableName2 
 ON TableName2.IP = TableName.IP AND TableName2.Username != TableName.Username
 WHERE TableName.Username = 'Foo'
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Users LEFT JOIN Users AS Users2 ON Users2.ip = Users.ip AND Users2.user != Users.user WHERE Users.user = "Foo" //Not quite working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a single = instead of double at the end. I updated my answer.